# Unable to display Twitter Bootstrap glyphicons properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I use `HtmlToPdfResult()` to create a PDF version of my web page.

There are some glyphicons in place.

From time to time i get my PDF version with second symbol shown.

[image: Glyphicons Problem]

Comment: What do you want in the second symbol?

Comment: It is the same page . 1st time it renders with icon , second time it renders with that strange font .

Comment: Works the same in Opera,Mozilla,Chrome .